# Start Tomcat WAR

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have installed a Tomcat server on my PC.

I have created a set of servlets in Eclipse and I exported in WAR format

When I deploy to the server and give it to boot I get the following error:

```
FALLO - No se pudo arrancar la aplicación en trayectoria de contexto /Middleware
FALLO - Encontrada excepción org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Middleware]]
```

If I go to the Tomcat log file for more details see the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [reunionServlet] and [servlet.ReunionServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/ReunionServlet] which is not permitted
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2457)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2139)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2100)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2093)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

What is the problem?

Do not know if the problem is with the file web.xml. Its content is as follows

[image]

Comment: Are you using Tomcat 7 and Servlet 3.0 features like adding the URL mapping in the servlet definition with `@WebServlet("someUrl")`?

Comment: To start a Tomcat WAR, just mention JBoss or WebSphere ;-)

Comment: Show us some of the code for the servlet.ReunionServlet class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the first three lines of your stacktrace, they tell you quite well what's going on: As javadev has answered correctly, you're mapping two servlets to the same URL-pattern. One of them is obviously in your web.xml, the other most likely in some annotation (as the third line of your stacktrace gives away).

Locate the offending servlet and change either the annotation or the web.xml declaration and you'll be fine.

Funny enough: The offending servlet seems to be the same in both cases - e.g. you have declared the mapping for ReunionServlet in web.xml and annotated servlet.ReunionServlet (your package name seems to be "servlet" - quite generic). So you basically just need to delete one of the two declarations and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Both of reunionServlet and servlet.ReunionServlet are mapped to the same URL-PATTERN /ReunionServlet, which is prohibited in a Servlet Container.
Remove one of the declarations.

Answer (score 0):

if ure using java ee  api library the problem might be there.
try to remove java EE 6 api library from the proyect and build again.

it works for me